# Button Hover Effect CSS both Buttons are moving

Tags: html, css, flat

I am trying to make a button design for my website. When the user hovers over the button, I want it to go down, just as if it was a real button that is being pressed down. It works, but If I have 2 buttons, it moves the other one down too. I suspect that the cause of that is the margin-top on the hover effect. But why does the other button move down too?
The code I am using is on the bottom.
If you want, I also have it on [codepen](http://codepen.io/MaxRumpf/pen/emPBNJ).

Greetings and thanks in advance,

Max Rumpf

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
        <script src=""
        <script src="base.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container">
           <button>Click Me!</button>
           <button>Hi</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?  family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 700;
}
body {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.container > button {
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0s;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #2980b9;
}
.container > button:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2980b9;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to align the buttons with

```
.container > button {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.container > button {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0s;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #2980b9;
}
.container > button:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2980b9;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Click Me!</button>
  <button>Hi</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update this css or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYqBjL

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700);
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-weight: 700;
}
body {
 background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 100px;
}
.container > button {
 font-size: 2em;
 background-color: #3498db;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 color: #ecf0f1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0s;
 border-bottom: 8px solid #2980b9;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.container > button:hover {
 border-bottom: 4px solid #2980b9;
}
```